# JQuery can't return xml value

Tags: jquery, xml

I have this simple xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<library>
    <item name="box_shelf">
        <imageback src="images/box_shelf_color.png"/>
        <outline src="images/box_shelf_outline.png"/>
        <sku>
            <wh sku="4696424171" />
            <ch sku="4696424179" />
            <choc sku="4696425863" />
            <ma sku="4696424175" />
        </sku>
    </item>
</library>
```

Loading the xml is fine. I then have a function to parse certain nodes.

```
function parseImageXml(mainNode,targetNode) {
            $(libraryXML).find('item').each(function() {

                if($(this).attr('name') == mainNode) {
                     var $temp = $(this).find(targetNode).attr('src');
                     console.log("******"+$temp);
                    return $temp;
                }

            });
}
```

The console log is fine with

```
******images/box_shelf_outline.png
******images/box_shelf_color.png
```

But when I try to return the value into variables, I get undefined.

```
var image_outline = parseImageXml("box_shelf","outline");
var image_back = parseImageXml("box_shelf","imageback");
console.log(image_outline+":"+image_back);

undefined:undefined
```

Any insight would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything from your parseImageXml function.  Try changing to the following:

```
       function parseImageXml(mainNode,targetNode) {
          var $temp; //Declare your scope variable.      
          $(libraryXML).find('item').each(function() {

            if($(this).attr('name') == mainNode) {
                 $temp = $(this).find(targetNode).attr('src');// Assign to the scoped variable
                 console.log("******"+$temp);
                return false;  //Exit your for each loop
            }

        });
        return $temp;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the value inside the `each` callback, so the return value of the outer function is still `undefined`. Make an array, push the values into it inside the callback, the return the array outside `each`.

```
function parseImageXml(mainNode, targetNode) {
    var targets = [];
    $(libraryXML).find('item').each(function() {

        if ($(this).attr('name') == mainNode) {
            var $temp = $(this).find(targetNode).attr('src');
            console.log("******" + $temp);
            targets.push($temp);
        }

    });
    return targets;
}

var image_outline = parseImageXml("box_shelf","outline")[0];
var image_back = parseImageXml("box_shelf","imageback")[0];
console.log(image_outline+":"+image_back);
```